# What does, 'AL lib: pulseaudio.c:612: Context did not connect: Access denied' mean?

Tags: c++, c, openal, pulseaudio

I'm getting the following error when running a simple OpenAL program:

> AL lib: pulseaudio.c:612: Context did not connect: Access denied

Interestingly, if I try playing audio then it plays correctly, although it sounds slightly distorted.

Below is the code that produces the error. It also happens if I initialize with ALUT.

```
#include <AL/al.h>
#include <AL/alc.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
  ALCdevice* dev;
  ALCcontext* ctx;
  dev = alcOpenDevice(NULL);
  ctx = alcCreateContext(dev, NULL);
  alcMakeContextCurrent(ctx);
  // cleanup
  alcMakeContextCurrent(NULL);
  alcDestroyContext(ctx);
  alcCloseDevice(dev);
  return 0;
}
```

What does the error mean? Can I fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I fixed it by changing `/etc/openal/alsoft.conf` (I'm using Arch Linux) to this:

```
drivers=alsa,pulse
```

The default checks Pulse first, which I didn't have installed.

Installing Pulse should fix it too.

Answer (score 1):

If it still doesn't fix it (for PulseAudio's users), try

```
cp  /etc/machine-id /var/lib/dbus/machine-id
```